# Can not find get_Item() method for ListTemplates

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I'm working on a C#/VSTO application for automate some tasks in MS Word.  I'm trying to change the start number of a numbered list using a ListTemplate.  I've seen several examples of accessing a ListTemplate like this:

```
ListTemplate template = 
    app.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery].ListTemplates.get_Item(ref n);
```

However, Visual Studio doesn't recognize get_Item() as a method for ListTemplates.  Other methods of ListTemplates are listed in the VS popup so I'm not sure what the issue is?  How do I go about referencing a ListTemplate?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need get_item?  Is it not just index qualifiers e.g. ListTemplates[index]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I check in VSTO there is no `get_Item` for `ListTemplates`. Instead, one uses the index. For example

```
ListTemplate template =app.ListGalleries[Word.WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery].ListTemplates[Word.WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery];
```